# Generate mesh faces for vertices in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm not sure if the answer is supposed to be blindingly obvious but it eludes me. I'm doing the 3D Graphics class on Udacity that uses three.js. I'm at a point where I'm required to generate a 3d mesh.

I've got the vertices all generating correctly, but I'm stuck at generating faces for them. I can't think of an obvious way to auto generate faces that don't overlap. I've searched and searched around the web but I can't find any information about it. I'm not sure if it's something stupidly obvious or just not very documented. Here's the code:

```
function PolygonGeometry(sides) {
    var geo = new THREE.Geometry();

    // generate vertices
    for ( var pt = 0 ; pt < sides; pt++ )
    {
        // Add 90 degrees so we start at +Y axis, rotate counterclockwise around
        var angle = (Math.PI/2) + (pt / sides) * 2 * Math.PI;

        var x = Math.cos( angle );
        var y = Math.sin( angle );

        // YOUR CODE HERE
        //Save the vertex location - fill in the code
        geo.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(x, y, 0) );
    }
    // YOUR CODE HERE
    // Write the code to generate minimum number of faces for the polygon.


    // Return the geometry object
    return geo;
}
```

I know the basic formula for the minimum number of faces is n-2. But I just can't think of a way to do this without faces overlapping. **I don't want anyone to do my work for me, I want to figure it out myself as much as I can. But is there anyone who can point me in the right direction or give me a formula or something?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are generating your vertices in a concave fashion and in a counterclockwise manner then if you have 3 sides (triangle) you connect vertex 0 with 1 with 2. If you have 4 sides (quad) you connect vertex 0 with 1 with 2 (first triangle) and then vertex 0 with 2 with 3. If you have 5 sides (pentagon) you connect vertex 0 with 1 with 2 (first triangle) then vertex 0 with 2 with 3 (second triangle and then vertex 0 with 3 with 4. I think you get the pattern.

Comment: So basically make a fan? I guess I was just over thinking the problem haha. Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

### You can automate your triangulation

For big polygons it can be quite a job to manually add the faces. You can automate the process of adding faces to the Mesh using the `triangulateShape` method in `THREE.Shape.Utils` like this:

```
var vertices = [your vertices array]
var holes = [];
var triangles, mesh;
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();

geometry.vertices = vertices;

triangles = THREE.Shape.Utils.triangulateShape ( vertices, holes );

for( var i = 0; i < triangles.length; i++ ){

    geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( triangles[i][0], triangles[i][1], triangles[i][2] ));

}

mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
```

Where `vertices` is your array of vertices and with `holes` you can define holes in your polygon.

**Note:** Be careful, if your polygon is self intersecting it will throw an error. Make sure your vertices array is representing a valid (non intersecting) polygon.

Comment: Note: [From r82](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/6773#issuecomment-264658462) it is `THREE.ShapeUtils.triangulateShape()`

Comment: Watch out not to run into the issue "THREE.ShapeUtils: Unable to triangulate polygon! in triangulate()", see https://stackoverflow.com/q/16158931/1066234 for details.