# Duplicate points in three.js font

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've used Facetype.js to convert a ttf font to a js font for three.js however I'm getting a number of duplicate point errors like so:

> THREE.Shape: Duplicate point 41.52:10.928 THREE.ShapeUtils: Unable to
>   triangulate polygon! in triangulate()

How do I fix these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either remove the duplicates from your geometry before you do the triangulation or use a different triangulation library for example `earcut.js`.

Earcut is less sensitive for flaws in your geometry definition (like duplicate points or intersecting edges). You can easily use a different triangulation library using an adapter that I made and shared here [on GitHub](https://github.com/Wilt/three.js_triangulation).

Just download the dependencies and do:

```
THREE.Triangulation.setLibrary( THREE.Triangulation.libraries.earcut );
```

With switching to earcut you will (most likely) also get some performance increase.

---

**Note:** *As long as your geometry looks fine you don't really need to worry about these error messages and you could just decide to ignore them as well.*

Comment: I'll give this a go and tick the answer all going well.  I know the error messages aren't detrimental but it's a real nuisance when testing.  Many thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

@Wilt, works well.  Worth pointing out to anyone using this library that if you are using it with earcut and you have already built your own renderer/environment/lights etc.  then all you need to do is include the following:

```
<!-- include the earcut triangulation library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="earcut.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="triangulation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="viewers/loader.js"></script>
```

and then set the library as mentioned at the start of your script.

```
/* set the triangulation library to earcut */
THREE.Triangulation.setLibrary( THREE.Triangulation.libraries.earcut );
```