# How to simplify shapes for triangulation with three.js and jsclipper

Tags: three.js, triangulation

I try to display geometry which is constructed by constructpath commands like moveto lineto beziercurveto in Three.js.
Therefore I create a THREE.ShapePath(); and execute the command toShapes(isClockwise).
After this I use THREE.ExtrudeBufferGeometry to create the 3D shape.

Unfortunately the shapes are sometimes really complex and are not created correctly which means they are distorted.

Using libtess as triangulation library solves some issues. But I have still distorted geometry.

Now I want to use jsclipper to simplify the shapes prior triangulation.

I modified three.js in such way:

in the method addShape in ExtrudeBufferGeometry I have added:

```js
$.each(vertices, function(index, item) {
           vertices[index]['X'] = vertices[index]['x']; 
           vertices[index]['Y'] = vertices[index]['y']; 
           delete vertices[index]['x'];
           delete vertices[index]['y'];
      });
      
      if (holes[0]) {
        for (i = 0; i < holes.length; i++ )  {
          $.each(holes[i], function(index, item) {
               holes[i][index]['X'] = holes[i][index]['x']; 
               holes[i][index]['Y'] = holes[i][index]['y']; 
               delete holes[i][index]['x'];
               delete holes[i][index]['y'];
          });
        }
      }
      
      var scale = 100;
      ClipperLib.JS.ScaleUpPaths([vertices], scale);
      if (holes[0]) {
        ClipperLib.JS.ScaleUpPaths(holes, scale);
      }
      vertices = ClipperLib.Clipper.SimplifyPolygons([vertices], ClipperLib.PolyFillType.pftNonZero);
                                             // or ClipperLib.PolyFillType.pftEvenOdd
      if (holes[0]) {
        holes = ClipperLib.Clipper.SimplifyPolygons(holes, ClipperLib.PolyFillType.pftNonZero);
                                             // or ClipperLib.PolyFillType.pftEvenOdd
      }
      
      
//      var cleandelta = 0.1; // 0.1 should be the appropriate delta in different cases
//      vertices = ClipperLib.Clipper.CleanPolygons([vertices], cleandelta * scale);
//      if (holes[0]) {
//        holes = ClipperLib.Clipper.CleanPolygons(holes, cleandelta * scale);
//      }
      
      
                                             
      ClipperLib.JS.ScaleDownPaths(vertices, scale);
      if (holes[0]) {
        ClipperLib.JS.ScaleDownPaths(holes, scale);
      }
      
      for (i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++ )  {
        $.each(vertices[i], function(index, item) {
             vertices[i][index]['x'] = vertices[i][index]['X']; 
             vertices[i][index]['y'] = vertices[i][index]['Y']; 
             delete vertices[i][index]['X'];
             delete vertices[i][index]['Y'];
        });
      }
      if (holes[0]) {
        for (i = 0; i < holes.length; i++ )  {
          $.each(holes[i], function(index, item) {
               holes[i][index]['x'] = holes[i][index]['X']; 
               holes[i][index]['y'] = holes[i][index]['Y']; 
               delete holes[i][index]['X'];
               delete holes[i][index]['Y'];
          });
        }
      }
```

Now I can see that the vertices are "reduced".

But var faces = ShapeUtils.triangulateShape( vertices, holes ); doesn't generate faces for some examples anymore.

Please can one help how to simplify the shapes correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit hard to figure out what the problem is actually. Clipper (also when using SimplifyPolygons or SimplifyPolygon) can only produce weakly-simple polygons, which means that there can be pseudo-duplicate points: although sequential coordinates are quaranteed to be not indentical, some of the next points can share the same coordinate. Also a coordinate can be on the line between two points.

After simplifying (or any other boolean operation) you could make a cleaning step using Offsetting with a small negative value: https://sourceforge.net/p/jsclipper/wiki/documentation/#clipperlibclipperoffsetexecute.

This possibly removes all of the pseudo-duplicate points.

I have made also a float version of Clipper (http://jsclipper.sourceforge.net/6.4.2.2_fpoint/). It is extensively tested, but because Angus Johnson, the author of the original C# Clipper (of which JS-version is ported from), has thought that using floats causes robustness problems although according to my tests the are no such, the original C# float version does not exists. The float version is simpler to use and you can try there a small negative offset: eg. -0.001 or -0.01.

You could also give a try to PolyTree or ExPolygons (https://sourceforge.net/p/jsclipper/wiki/ExPolygons%20and%20PolyTree%206/). ExPolygons can be used to get holes and contours and PolyTree can be used to get the full parent-child-relationship of holes and contours.

The last resort is a broken-pen-nib -function. It detects all pseudo-duplicate points and make a broken-pen-nib -effect to them, so that the result is free of any duplicates. The attached images shows what this effect means using large nib-effect-value to make the effect meaning clearer. [Three.js polygon triangulation fails in pseudo duplicate points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158931/three-js-polygon-triangulation-fails-in-pseudo-duplicate-points). There are a discussion https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3386 of this subject.

[image]
[image]

```js
  // Make polygons to simple by making "a broken pen tip" effect on each semi-adjacent (duplicate) vertex
  // ORIGPOLY can be a contour
  // or exPolygon structure

  function BreakPenNibs(ORIGPOLY, dist, scale)
  {
    if (!dist || dist < 0) return;
    var sqrt = Math.sqrt;
    var allpoints = {}, point = {};
    var key = "";
    var currX = 0.0,
      currY = 0.0;
    var prevX = 0.0,
      prevY = 0.0;
    var nextX = 0.0,
      nextY;
    var x = 0.0,
      y = 0.0,
      length = 0.0,
      i = 0,
      duplcount = 0,
      j = 0;
    var prev_i = 0,
      next_i = 0,
      last_i;
    var extra_vertices = new Array(100),
      moved_vertices = new Array(100);

    // Get first all duplicates
    var duplicates = new Array(100),
      indexi = "",
      indexstr = "",
      arraystr = "",
      polys, outer, holes;
    if (ORIGPOLY instanceof Array) 
    {
      outer = ORIGPOLY;
    }
    else if (ORIGPOLY.outer instanceof Array) 
    {
      outer = ORIGPOLY.outer;
    }

      else return;
    if (ORIGPOLY.holes instanceof Array) holes = ORIGPOLY.holes;
    else holes = [];
    polys = [outer].concat(holes);
    var polys_length = polys.length;
    // Get first max lenght of arrays
    var max_index_len = 0;
    var arr_len;
    i = polys_length;
    while (i--)
    {
      arr_len = polys[i].length;
      if (arr_len > max_index_len) max_index_len = arr_len;
    }
    max_index_len = max_index_len.toString().length;
    var max_polys_length = polys_length.toString().length;
    var poly;
    j = polys_length;
    var scaling = scale/10;
    while (j--)
    {
      poly = polys[j];
      ilen = poly.length;
      i = ilen;
      while (i--)
      {
        point = poly[i];
        //key = Math.round(point.X) + ":" + Math.round(point.Y);
        
        key = (Math.round(point.X / scaling) * scaling)
        + ":" + (Math.round(point.Y / scaling) * scaling);
        indexi = allpoints[key];
        if (typeof (indexi) != "undefined")
        {
          // first found duplicate
          duplicates[duplcount] = indexi;
          duplcount++;

          arraystr = j.toString();
          while (arraystr.length < max_polys_length) arraystr = "0" + arraystr;
          indexstr = i.toString();
          while (indexstr.length < max_index_len) indexstr = "0" + indexstr;
          duplicates[duplcount] = arraystr + "." + indexstr;
          duplcount++;
        }
        arraystr = j.toString();
        while (arraystr.length < max_polys_length) arraystr = "0" + arraystr;
        indexstr = i.toString();
        while (indexstr.length < max_index_len) indexstr = "0" + indexstr;

        allpoints[key] = arraystr + "." + indexstr;
      }
    }
    if (!duplcount) return;

    duplicates.length = duplcount;
    duplicates.sort();
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(duplicates));

    var splitted, poly_index = 0,
      nth_dupl = 0;
    var prev_poly_index = -1;
    poly_index = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < duplcount; j++)
    {
      splitted = duplicates[j].split(".");

      poly_index = parseInt(splitted[0], 10);
      if (poly_index != prev_poly_index) nth_dupl = 0;
      else nth_dupl++;
      i = parseInt(splitted[1], 10);
      poly = polys[poly_index];
      len = poly.length;
      if (poly[0].X === poly[len - 1].X &&
        poly[0].Y === poly[len - 1].Y)
      {
        last_i = len - 2;
      }
      else
      {
        last_i = len - 1;
      }
      point = poly[i];

      // Calculate "broken pen tip" effect
      // for current point by finding
      // a coordinate at a distance dist
      // along the edge between current and
      // previous point
      // This is inlined to maximize speed
      currX = point.X;
      currY = point.Y;
      if (i === 0) prev_i = last_i; // last element in array
      else prev_i = i - 1;

      prevX = poly[prev_i].X;
      prevY = poly[prev_i].Y;
      
      x=0;y=0;
      if (!point.Collinear)
      {
        length = sqrt((-currX + prevX) * (-currX + prevX) + (currY - prevY) * (currY - prevY));

//console.log(length);
        x = currX - (dist * (currX - prevX)) / length;
        y = currY - (dist * (currY - prevY)) / length;
      }
        // save the found (calculated) point
        moved_vertices[j] = {
          X: x,
          Y: y,
          Collinear:point.Collinear,
          index: i,
          poly_index: poly_index
        };
      
      // "broken nib effect" for next point also
      if (i == len - 1) next_i = 0;
      else next_i = i + 1;
      nextX = poly[next_i].X;
      nextY = poly[next_i].Y;
      x=0;y=0;
      if (!point.Collinear)
      {
      length = sqrt((-currX + nextX) * (-currX + nextX) + (currY - nextY) * (currY - nextY));
      x = currX - (dist * (currX - nextX)) / length;
      y = currY - (dist * (currY - nextY)) / length;
      }
        // save the found (calculated) point
      extra_vertices[j] = {
        X: x,
        Y: y,
        Collinear:point.Collinear,
        index: i + nth_dupl,
        poly_index: poly_index
      };
      prev_poly_index = poly_index;
        
    }

    moved_vertices.length = extra_vertices.length = duplcount;
    //console.log("MOVED:" + JSON.stringify(moved_vertices));
    //console.log("EXTRA:" + JSON.stringify(extra_vertices));

    // Update moved coordinates
    i = duplcount;
    var point2;
    while (i--)
    {
      point = moved_vertices[i];
      x = point.X;
      y = point.Y;
      // Faster than isNaN: http://jsperf.com/isnan-alternatives
      if (x != x || x == Infinity || x == -Infinity) continue;
      if (y != y || y == Infinity || y == -Infinity) continue;
      point2 = polys[point.poly_index][point.index];
      point2.X = point.X;
      point2.Y = point.Y;
      point2.Collinear = point.Collinear;
    }

    // Add an extra vertex
    // This is needed to remain the angle of the next edge
    for (i = 0; i < duplcount; i++)
    {
      point = extra_vertices[i];
      x = point.X;
      y = point.Y;
      // Faster than isNaN: http://jsperf.com/isnan-alternatives
      if (x != x || x == Infinity || x == -Infinity) continue;
      if (y != y || y == Infinity || y == -Infinity) continue;
      polys[point.poly_index].splice(point.index + 1, 0,
      {
        X: point.X,
        Y: point.Y,
        Collinear: point.Collinear
      });
    }
    
    // Remove collinear points
    // and for some reason coming
    // sequential duplicates
    // TODO: check why seq. duplicates becomes
    j = polys.length;
    var prev_point = null;
    while (j--)
    {
      poly = polys[j];
      ilen = poly.length;
      i = ilen;
      while (i--)
      {
        point = poly[i];
        if(prev_point!=null && point.X == prev_point.X && point.Y == prev_point.Y) poly.splice(i, 1);
        else
        if(point.Collinear) poly.splice(i, 1);
      prev_point = point;
      }
    }
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(polys));
    // because original array is modified, no need to return anything
  }
  
  var BreakPenNipsOfExPolygons = function (exPolygons, dist, scale)
  {
    var i = 0,
      j = 0,
      ilen = exPolygons.length,
      jlen = 0;
    for (; i < ilen; i++)
    {
      //if(i!=4) continue;
      BreakPenNibs(exPolygons[i], dist, scale);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Do have an updated version of the [5.0 demo](http://jsclipper.sourceforge.net/5.0.2.2/main_demo.html) running on 6.x?

Comment: These are the newest:
LIVE DEMO: http://jsclipper.sourceforge.net/6.4.2.2/main_demo.html

LIVE DEMO (FPoint):
http://jsclipper.sourceforge.net/6.4.2.2_fpoint/main_demo.html