# How to add faces to THREE.BufferGeometry?

Tags: javascript, three.js, vertex, buffer-geometry

I have created programmatically a simple mesh:

```
var CreateSimpleMesh = new function () {
    var xy = [],
        maxX = 7,
        maxY = 10,
        river = [[0, 5], [0, 4], [1, 3], [2, 2], [3, 2], [4, 1], [5, 1], [6, 0]],
        grassGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry(),
        grassVertexPositions = []

    this.init = function () {
        for (i = 0; i < maxX; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < maxY; j++) {
                xy.push([i, j])
            }
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < xy.length; i++) {
            grassVertexPositions.push([xy[i][0], xy[i][1], 0])
            grassVertexPositions.push([xy[i][0] + 1, xy[i][1], 0])
            grassVertexPositions.push([xy[i][0], xy[i][1] + 1, 0])

            grassVertexPositions.push([xy[i][0] + 1, xy[i][1] + 1, 0])
            grassVertexPositions.push([xy[i][0], xy[i][1] + 1, 0])
            grassVertexPositions.push([xy[i][0] + 1, xy[i][1], 0])
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < grassVertexPositions.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < river.length; j++) {
                if (river[j][0] == grassVertexPositions[i][0] && river[j][1] == grassVertexPositions[i][1]) {
                    grassVertexPositions[i][2] = -0.5
                }
            }
        }

        var grassVertices = new Float32Array(grassVertexPositions.length * 3)

        for (var i = 0; i < grassVertexPositions.length; i++) {
            grassVertices[i * 3 + 0] = grassVertexPositions[i][0];
            grassVertices[i * 3 + 1] = grassVertexPositions[i][1];
            grassVertices[i * 3 + 2] = grassVertexPositions[i][2];
        }

        grassGeometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(grassVertices, 3))

    var grassMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x00ff00}),
        grassMesh = new THREE.Mesh(grassGeometry, grassMaterial)

        grassMesh.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2
        Test.getScene().add(grassMesh);
    }
}
```

Problem is that this mesh has only vertices. I have tried to add to it faces like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795348/generate-mesh-faces-for-vertices-in-three-js) question using THREE.Shape.Utils.triangulateShape but BufferGeometry is different than normal geometry and it does not work. Is it possible to add faces to BufferGeometry?

EDIT:
[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/grz671u9/)

Comment: You need to start with an example that works and then slowly modify it.

Comment: This one is working.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how to create a mesh having `BufferGeometry`. This is the simpler "non-indexed" `BufferGeometry` where vertices are not shared.

```
// non-indexed buffer geometry
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

// number of triangles
var NUM_TRIANGLES = 10;

// attributes
var positions = new Float32Array( NUM_TRIANGLES * 3 * 3 );
var normals   = new Float32Array( NUM_TRIANGLES * 3 * 3 );
var colors    = new Float32Array( NUM_TRIANGLES * 3 * 3 );
var uvs       = new Float32Array( NUM_TRIANGLES * 3 * 2 );

var color = new THREE.Color();
var scale = 15;
var size = 5;
var x, y, z;

for ( var i = 0, l = NUM_TRIANGLES * 3; i < l; i ++ ) {

    if ( i % 3 === 0 ) {

        x = ( Math.random() - 0.5 ) * scale;
        y = ( Math.random() - 0.5 ) * scale;
        z = ( Math.random() - 0.5 ) * scale;

    } else {

        x = x + size * ( Math.random() - 0.5 );
        y = y + size * ( Math.random() - 0.5 );
        z = z + size * ( Math.random() - 0.5 );

    }

    var index = 3 * i;

    // positions
    positions[ index     ] = x;
    positions[ index + 1 ] = y;
    positions[ index + 2 ] = z;

    //normals -- we will set normals later

    // colors
    color.setHSL( i / l, 1.0, 0.5 );
    colors[ index     ] = color.r;
    colors[ index + 1 ] = color.g;
    colors[ index + 2 ] = color.b;

    // uvs
    uvs[ index     ] = Math.random(); // just something...
    uvs[ index + 1 ] = Math.random();

}

geometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( positions, 3 ) );
geometry.addAttribute( 'normal', new THREE.BufferAttribute( normals, 3 ) );
geometry.addAttribute( 'color', new THREE.BufferAttribute( colors, 3 ) );
geometry.addAttribute( 'uv', new THREE.BufferAttribute( uvs, 2 ) );

// optional
geometry.computeBoundingBox();
geometry.computeBoundingSphere();

// set the normals
geometry.computeVertexNormals(); // computed vertex normals are orthogonal to the face for non-indexed BufferGeometry
```

See the three.js examples for many additional examples of creating `BufferGeometry`. Also check out the source code for `PlaneGeometry` and `SphereGeometry`, which are reasonably easy to understand.

three.js r.143

Comment: Can you explain why you created uvs like this?

Comment: Good point. There was no reason, other than to be in [0,1]. I changed to something "less unusual". : - )

Comment: Maybe but I'm starting to learn 3d and Three.js so I don't really know what I'm doing for most of times. Thank you very much for help, I will examine your fiddle.

Comment: What should I do if I want to use texture instead of color?

Comment: @BartoszKrzeszewski Maybe you should accept the answer...?

Comment: I can't accept this answer. I was asking about faces and there is nothing about them in the answer. But I'm grateful for help in comments.

Comment: The first 9 elements in the `positions` array contain the x,y,z coordinates of the 3 vertices of the first face. The next 9 element specify the vertices of the 2nd face.

Answer (score 1):

You can add faces using three.js internal function- `fromBufferGeometry`. In your case it would be something like this.

```
var directGeo = new THREE.Geometry();
directGeo.fromBufferGeometry(grassGeometry);
```

Then use `directGeo` to build your mesh, and it will have faces.